# Changing elevation values of DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I am no expert in QGIS and I've already spend quite some time to find an answer to this, but I could not.

Could anyone tell me how to change the elevation value of DEM?

The one I have has been created for a small area, done with drone footage, and it has for some reason values that lie approx. 30 meters lower than the elevation a.s.l. really is (according to reference maps).

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if he has solved your question

Answer (score 5):

After loading the DEM, you can use the `Raster | Raster calculator` menu option to modify values.

For example, here the raster 'Tsavo.dem' was loaded (it appears as band Tsavo@1), and the calculator will produce a new TIF called tsavoMinus30.tif using the calculation `"Tsavo@1" - 30`

[image]